# Python SSO: pysaml2 and python3-saml

Tags: python, single-sign-on, saml, shibboleth

I new to SSO and I've only tried `pysaml2` by far.

I am also aware of `python3-saml` library (and its `python-saml` Python 2 flavour).

I need to use one of those with Shibboleth, if it is relevant.

What are the pros and cons of `pysaml2` and `python3-saml`?

---

Update:

As for 2019, I still find python3-saml to be the best option if you need to implement an SP. It is not flawless (sorry @smartin, hhehe), but it will give you much less headache than pysaml2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both projects are compatible with Shibboleth.

pysaml2 is older than python3-saml, right now both support py2 and py3. Both are kinda active and documented.

python3-saml follows the structure of Onelogin's SAML toolkit so if you used any other toolkit before ([php-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml), [ruby-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml), [java-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml)), will be easy for you to handle with it (similar methods, same settings).

**Differences**

*Crypto:*

- pysaml2 uses as dependecy [pycryptodome](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome) to handle with cryptography and implements its own [xmldsig](https://github.com/rohe/pysaml2/blob/master/src/saml2/xmldsig/__init__.py) and [xmlenc](https://github.com/rohe/pysaml2/blob/master/src/saml2/xmlenc/__init__.py) classes (to manipulate signatures and encryption on XMLs).
- python3-saml uses as dependecy [python-xmlsec](https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec) and delegates on it the signature/encryption of XML elements.

*Functionality:*

- pysaml2 let you deploy an Identity Provider or a Service Provider
- python3-saml is focused on the Service Provider

*Settings:*

In my opinion, python3-saml is easier than pysaml2, settings are more precise and its repo contains code examples on how integrate a [django](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml/tree/master/demo-django) or a [flask](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml/tree/master/demo-flask) app and a guide at the [docs](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml#demo-flask-1).

**Note: I'm the author of python3-saml**

Comment: Any guides on how to use pysaml2 for Odoo with Shiboleth?

Comment: How to provide URI in <ds:Reference> in SSO metadata ? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I just come from trying to integrate my existing authentication mechanisms with pysaml2, and I'd just like to emphasize how easily you are completely right on this account.

Comment: I tried today to work with both libraries. `pysaml2`'s example didn't work while the one in `python3-saml` works. There is an example website that make it clear to see whats going on. I recommend the chrome extension `SAML-tracer` to see the requests on the fly.